Eurasia Airports without body scanners
I am looking to plan my trip around the most non-invasive airports.

I am happy to go through metal detectors

I don't mind my luggage being thoroughly searched

I don't mind a pat-down

My only concern is the body scanner, which I do not trust for health reasons.

I have read UAE do not have body scanners, is this still true?

I have read Turkey has body scanners, can you opt for a pat down?

I have read EU airports allow you to opt-out

can anyone recommend major Eurasian airports (connecting east to west) where there are either no body scanner, or opting out is possible?


Thanks for reading. I have been reading these forums and I feel good that I am not the only one concerned about the scanners. I can especially understand frequent-flyers not wanting to be scanned every time their travel.

I don't know about Asia, but in the US you can request not to use a body scanner.  This of course means you'll be subjected an more invasive pat-down.  So perhaps you need to add "is opting out possible?" to your list.

Lots of places in Europe and Canada have the opt out option.

Also don't believe internet forums when it cones to questions about your health.

If you're concerned about radiation from body scanners, then wait until you see how much more radiation you get from the sky while you're actually flying. And it's not the good kind.

the body scanner is better for your health (or less risky, choose your words) than a dental X-ray. Just don't wear your tinfoil hat while going through one!

@GregHewgill Just to be pedantic, the body scanners emit non-ionizing radiation, while on the the flight you are subject to ionizing radiation.  What is more important is the type of radiation and not the amount.

@DJClayworth Ideally a random forum that is focussed on facts rather than conspiracy theories should be able to point you towards true information about health.

It is upsetting that an someone will say "conspiracy theory" about doubting the safety of a medical device. Would you believe all safety data about vaccines?
Medical negligence is the 3rd leading cause of death in the United States. Please recall Backscatter body scanners were removed from airports because they were not safe - can guarantee you 10 years from now they will save the same about millimeter wave scanners.

@Traveler1 Given that backscatter devices were removed over 10 years ago, mentioning them is irrelevant. And unless you have information about mm wave devices that is not publicly known, then you are sampling spreading FUD.  And given that you mentioned vaccines, what vaccines are "unsafe"?  Because that is delving into conspiracy theory territory.

@Traveler1 you ARE promoting, or at least believing in, conspiracy theories. Having that pointed out to you is a good thing, you may learn something.

It's optional in the EU.
Section 4.1.1.10 of Consolidated text: Commission Implementing Regulation (EU) 2015/1998 of 5 November 2015 laying down detailed measures for the implementation of the common basic standards on aviation security, Document 02015R1998-20240901, says in part

Passengers shall be entitled to opt out from a security scanner. In this case the passenger shall be screened by an alternative screening method including at least a hand search in accordance with Attachment 4-A of Commission Implementing Decision C(2015) 8005. When the security scanner alarms, the cause of the alarm shall be resolved.
Before being screened by a security scanner, the passenger shall be informed of the technology used, the conditions associated to its use and the possibility to opt out from a security scanner.


Same in the US. You just need to tell the TSA agent "I opt out" and they will give a you a manual pat down. Bring extra time.

Vienna International Airport does not use body scanners in their facilities. Source: Personal experience and VIE website.
